# GWT DatePicker: How to change the number of days in the month of FEB to either 29 or 30?

Tags: gwt, datepicker

I am working on CustomDatePicker. I have a situation where i need the number of days in the month of FEB to be either 29 or 30 days. But i am not able to achieve that. I am not interested in creating a class which extends BaseCalendar.java of sun.util.calendar package. Are there any other methods to achieve it???

Am working with GWT 2.4.0

Comment: ...so you want to represent February as having more days than it actually does? Maybe I'm crazy to ask why, but...why?

Comment: @ChrisCashwell He is wanting it for Islamic calendar, I think, there are feb 29,39 in other calendars: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_30

Comment: I wonder if there's a Locale setting that would alter the calendar automatically?

Comment: Locale settings will not give you the other versions of calendar. It just changes the month name and week names to corresponding locale or should i just say translates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible at present.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7173